# How to add headers to a httparty call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

Im trying to add headers to my api call

Heres what i have tried at the moment

```
api1 = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('apiurllink' + tmname + '&date=' + fromdate + ' TO ' + todate + '', :headers => {"Authorization" => "Bearer apikey"})).parsed_response
```

This is returning this error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Your attempt is raising a TypeError since you are passing the `:headers => {"Authorization" => "Bearer apikey"}` hash to `URI.encode` and not HTTParty.get.

```
api1 = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('apiurllink' + tmname + '&date=' + fromdate + ' TO ' + todate + ''), :headers => {"Authorization" => "Bearer apikey"}).parsed_response
```

A better way is to use the `query` option and get HTTParty to construct the query string for you.

```
response = HTTParty.get('/someuri', 
  query: {
    date: "#{fromdate} TO #{todate}",
    foo: "bar"
  },
  headers: {
    "Authorization" => "Bearer apikey"
  }
)
```